# MySQL Query between 2 tables and find not null

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables, one for the articles and one for some attributes
I have some products that have one attribute with value Yes. I also have other attributes.
The query that i want to create is to get all products that don't have the Attribute 7.

You can check the mysql tables.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f75eec/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select a.ArticleID,a.ArticleTitle,aa.ArticleID,aa.AttrID,aa.StringValue
from cms_articles a
inner join cms_attr_art aa on aa.ArticleID = a.ArticleID
where a.ArticleID NOT IN (select ArticleID from cms_attr_art where AttrID = 7);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query

```
SELECT a.ArticleId, b.attrId
FROM cms_articles a
INNER JOIN cms_attr_art b
ON a.articleId = b.articleId
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM cms_attr_art c WHERE c.articleid = a.articleid AND c.attrId = 7)
```